# Safely parallelizing a for loop containing fnctions of vectors

Tags: c++, openmp

In one part of my code, I have a slow for loop which I wish to paralleling. However, I'm not very experienced with using openmp and I afraid if there is any mistake in the way I have paralleled the loop. Could any experted guy tell me if there could be any mistake in this part of my code? Any help is HIGHLY appreciated.

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(5)
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
            double sum_sin = 0.0, sum_cos = 0.0;

            for (vector<int>::iterator it = box_neighbors[bx[i]].begin(); it != box_neighbors[bx[i]].end(); ++it)
                {
                for (vector<int>::iterator itp = box_particles[*it].begin(); itp != box_particles[*it].end(); ++itp)
                     {
                     if(dist(x[i], y[i], x[*itp], y[*itp], L) < R0_two)
                        {
                        sum_sin+= sin(theta[*itp]);
                        sum_cos+= cos(theta[*itp]);  
                        }
                     }
                }
            theta_new[i] = atan(sum_sin/sum_cos);
            if (sum_cos < 0 && sum_sin < 0) //theta should be in (-pi,pi)
                {
                theta_new[i]-= pi;
                }
            else if (sum_cos < 0 && sum_sin > 0)
                {
                theta_new[i] = pi + theta_new[i];
                }
            }
```

Comment: You should format your code first. I am not an expert, but the code seems OK for me.

Comment: What do you mean by format my code? @NanXiao

Comment: I mean it seems messy, so please make it look-friendly.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to average the sums in your current loop (you can remove the `/= count;` lines), as you don't use them that way (both `atan` and comparisons against zero will work even with summed value). And you can use probably `const_iterator`s.

Comment: And `sum_sin/sum_cos` can end with division by zero (probably not very likely with many particles, still should happen often enough to be observable).

Comment: @Ped7g Your previous comment: Does it causes any problem? Because atan(0.0006/0) is equal to 1.5708

Comment: @Ped7g Your first comment: thank you, I didn't notice that befor

Comment: What do you mean by : you can use probably const_iterators @Ped7g  why should I use it?

Comment: About division by zero: if you know, what it does, then comment the code with the knowledge, why it doesn't matter (also watch for any performance penalty incurred, if that silent failure is cheap, or not), but having it in code without comment is plain bug upon code review. If the code explains why it is ok, then it is ok.

Comment: About const_iterator - whenever it makes sense, use `const` in C++. It allows the compiler optimizer to be more aggressive in certain cases, when it *knows* that something can't change during the `for` loop. With iterators it means no element will be deleted from list/vector, which *may* sometimes lead to more optimal machine code. Also it *does* catch semantic bugs, when you meant something to not change, but you accidentally wrote code trying to change it, then it will fail on `const`.

Comment: BTW, if resulting theta should be in -pi, +pi, and you know it is at most 1*pi away, it will be cheaper to do `if (new_theta <= -pi) new_theta += pi;` `if (pi <= new_theta) new_theta -= pi;`, instead of the sin/cos `&&` composed test. But I'm not sure, if this is identical (if I understand that code correctly). EDIT: it is NOT, sorry, now I understand. ... that said, is this some kind of averaging angle to near particles? How would simple theta_sum/count average (wrapped to -pi,+pi range) work then, totally bogus values or good-enough approximation?

Comment: You may also want to check [`atan2`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/atan2/), wouldn't that resolve those ending `if`? (as always with performance, measure it, it's highly likely the compiler's implementation of `atan2` will win over your `atan + 2x if fix`, but without measuring it's just worthless guessing).

Comment: And the whole `if(dist(x[i], y[i], x[*itp], y[*itp], L) < R0_two)` construction may be unreasonably slow... depends on the pre-selection of data. If your neighbour box already filters out most of the particles far away and the `if` is just final fine filtering to have exact boundary, then it is quite ok. But if lot of data going in are way too far (already by single axis), you should use some `bool dist_less_than(..., R0_two)` and reject big delta early without calculating full distance. Also avoid `sqrt` where only `sqr` comparison is enough. Code that doesn't exist is fastest, MT helps less.